# What is the first movie to use a VCR (or recording device) to trick an adversary?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history

I was watching ["Columbo: Playback"](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=EuNzXaTgJuG6ggem64KABw&q=Columbo%20Playback&oq=Columbo%20Playback&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.78.2768..2992...0.0..0.139.1425.10j5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0i10.uis4IOciqAs&ved=0ahUKEwiksezcmL_kAhVhneAKHaa1AHAQ4dUDCAc&uact=5), and the murderer uses a video security system to cover up a murder.

It got me thinking, what was the first movie to use video playback to trick another character? The other two notable examples I can think of is *Speed* and *Ocean's Eleven*.

Comment: Do you require it to be a video loop specifically? Or is the effect (i.e. the Polaroid example) sufficient?

Answer (score 5):

There are several different versions of this appearing in television, however the earliest film version that I could find was the 1968 Italian film, *[Danger: Diabolik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger:_Diabolik)*. Directed by de Laurentis, and a score by Ennio Morricone, it features a criminal named Diabolik who plans large heists for his girlfriend. It was an adaptation from existing comics at the time.

In this, Diabolik is planning to steal a costly emerald necklace. The only video I could find is a Spanish subtitled version. [In this, starting at ~ 46:55](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpwZi7Mh-eo) Diabolik scales the walls of castle to enter the room. Once in, he sees the camera, takes a Polaroid of the room and places it in front of the camera.

Comment: Note: I realize this is not the same as a video loop, but is the same effect. I asked for clarification from the OP, however may not get a response as they are no longer a registered user.